# Azure Webjobs History

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I'm trying to build a webpage where I need to show the webjob's history filtered by the date.

Based on the information provided by the [Webjobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API), I made a call to *https:// {sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/history* which returned only the top 50 results.

Is there an another way to retrieve history data based on a specific date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only returns 50 results because that is all it saves by default. If you want to change this, you can set the `WEBJOBS_HISTORY_SIZE` App Setting to a high value in the Azure Portal.